# Is it possible to install ubuntu via ubuntu's source code

Tags: system-installation

If I install compiled code, I don't see if the same open source code is actually compiled there. So this is why I would like to install OS via source code.

Comment: What do you think you would be installing?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I want to install Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS via source code to my computer.

Comment: If you want to install an OS from source, I think [you're looking for Arch](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Build_System). Ubuntu's goal has always been to make Linux accessible, which precludes the option to start from a digital heartbeat and work your way up.

Comment: You may be interested in this question and the accepted answer there: https://askubuntu.com/q/1316954/1157519

Comment: But to install Arch linux I also need to start with compiled iso file. Can I start with open source code? I don't want to use compiled code to install it.

Comment: Maybe do a search for "Linux From Scratch".

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible. However, it can be quite tedious.

The source code of Ubuntu packages are freely available hosted online (mostly at http://launchpad.net), and as apt-able Debian *source packages* (not to be confused with more common pre-compiled *binary packages*)

The basic workflow is that you **download** a source package, **build** it into a binary package (including compiling), then **install** the binary package.

There's a lot of skill baked into that workflow, like diagnosing compile errors and understanding how both kinds of packaging work.

Since you seem to be asking specifically about the initial install of a system, it's mostly the same...but requires **chrooting** from an already-running system in order to compile and install your kernel and initial package set.

If you are seeking a step-by-step how-do-I-do-this tutorial, that would be much too long to fit AskUbuntu's format. Start with the *skills* required to install using a chroot and how to download and compile source packages. After the few months it takes you to learn those skills competently, you will know what you need to know.

Comment: Why should I diagnose errors if the open source was already properly prepared and all the other work was done before the .iso file was produced for people to download?

Comment: what is chrooting?

Comment: How could I learn chrooting?

Comment: Maybe I should try to build my own operating system to learn all this things?

Comment: I know how to compile single program :D. I know c++ basics.

Comment: Now it seems to me that it is not worth taking my time to do all this things, it's too complicated.